# How do I use a generated or temporary password when creating a new user through membership in C# MVC3?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-membership

I'm creating a client contact using Membership.CreateUser and I'd like to supply a generated password each time a contact is created. The production team will be setting up accounts for new client contacts.

The problem I'm running into is when I pass through the generic password, the method fails. When I supply my own password through the model it works fine.

I'm looking for a work-around or a better practice.

Thanks in advance for you help!

Here is an example of the code:

```
        [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult RegisterClientContact(RegisterClientContactViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //Create Generic password - First initial Last initial 1234
            string genericPassword = model.FirstName.Substring(0, 1).ToLower() + model.LastName.Substring(0, 1).ToLower() + "1234";


            //Attempt to register the Client Contact
            MembershipCreateStatus createStatus;
            Membership.CreateUser(model.Email, genericPassword, model.Email, null, null, true, null, out createStatus);



            if (createStatus == MembershipCreateStatus.Success)
            {
                Roles.AddUserToRole(model.Email, "Client");
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.Email, false /*create persistent cookie*/);

                Person person = new Person();
                person.FirstName = model.FirstName;
                person.LastName = model.LastName;
                person.Email = model.Email;
                person.Phone = model.Phone;
                person.Active = true;

                db.Persons.Add(person);
                db.SaveChanges();

                ClientContact clientPerson = new ClientContact();
                clientPerson.ClientPersonId = person.Id;
                clientPerson.Title = model.Title;
                clientPerson.ClientId = model.ClientId;

                db.ClientPersons.Add(clientPerson);
                db.SaveChanges();

                return RedirectToAction("Index", "ClientContact");
            }
        }

        return View("An Error has occured");
    }
```

By the way, it seems I should be able to pass in my own password given [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membership.generatepassword.aspx) article.

Comment: Could you post your membership tag inside web.config, so that we can see what configuration is missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's likely due to the fact that your default passwords don't meet the ASP.NET Membership default password complexity requirements.  The default password needs to be **7 characters**.  The exception should tell you exactly what the problem is.  See the following MSDN page for more details on how to configure Membership's minRequiredPasswordLength setting.

[Membership.MinRequiredPasswordLength Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membership.minrequiredpasswordlength)

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not it. I had set the min length to 6 which always is the case with the scheme I made above.

Comment: When you say "the method" fails, how does it fail?  Is an exception thrown?

Comment: Also, what does the out parameter "createStatus" return when it fails?